# I can't complete the update of WordPress from the admin panel

Tags: wordpress

- Overview
  I can't update my WordPress from the admin panel=>Update (the admin panel is locked in the middle).
  WordPress itself is trying to update to "WordPress 5.9".
- What I tried
  Stop all plugins and update WordPress.
  Set the permissions of "upgrade" and "plugins" directories under the WordPress directory and wp-content to 777 or 704, and stop all plugins.
  To enable debug.log, I added the following to wp-config.php and tried to update, but no debug.log appears under wp-content.
  Added statement=>define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
  Update with browser cache cleared
  Checked PHP execution time in wp-config.php=>set_time_limit(600) and it was specified as 10 minutes, so it seems to be fine.
- What I want to ask you
  Even if I do all of the above things in parallel, I can't update WordPress (the process stops in the middle).
  Can you tell me if there is any other reason why WordPress can't be updated? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a manual update at that point.

Download the current/or version you need and once you’ve downloaded it, extract the zip file to your computer. Then, open the folder that contains all of the WordPress files and delete the following items:

The wp-config-sample.php file.

The wp-config.php file (you might not see this file – just make sure to delete it if it’s there). The wp-content folder.

Once you’ve deleted those items, upload the remaining files/folders to your server via FTP. When prompted about duplicate files by your FTP client, tell it to overwrite all files: